# How do I calculate high water extents?

Tags: arcgis-pro, dem, flood

Could someone suggest the right path to follow if I were looking to calculate the high water extents or potential flooding that could occur on a tidal river.  I am working in ArcGIS Pro and have access to a DEM for the area, but not much else for now.  Is this possible with just this data?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried searching this forum yet..... try typing "flood mapping" into the search box.